# "NOTICE: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to int" during insert operation

Tags: php, pdo

My code is working, but there is a **NOTICE** on the if satement while running. I tried to solve it, but I can't. 
**Notice error:** Notice: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to int in D:\wamp\www\pdo\addOrders.php on line 30
**here is my code:**

```
<?php
$host = 'localhost';
    $dbname = 'test';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '';

    try 
    {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
       /* echo "Connected to $dbname at $host successfully.<br/>"; */
    }
    catch (PDOException $e) 
    {
        echo "<h3>Error:</h3>". $e->getMessage();
    }


$customer_id=addslashes($_GET['customer_id']);

$t=time();
$d=date("Y-m-d",$t);


$sql= "INSERT INTO `test`.`orders` (`customer_id`, `date`) VALUES ('$customer_id', '$d');";

$result =$conn->query($sql);
$lastid = $conn->lastInsertId();

if($result==1)
{

    $query = "select * from `orders` where customer_id='$customer_id'";
    $result = $conn->query($query);
    $dbvalue = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    $customer_id=$dbvalue->customer_id;
    $date=$dbvalue->date;


    $details = array(
    'status'=>'sucess', 
    'message'=>'customer added sucessfully',
    'id' => $lastid, 
    'customer_id' => $customer_id,
    'date' => $date,
    );

    echo  json_encode($details);
}
else
{
    $detail = array(
    'status'=>'unsucess',   
    'message'=>'cannot add customer',

    );

    echo  json_encode($detail);
}
?>
```

Comment: `$conn->query()` returns a `PDOStatement` object. You're trying to compare that to `== 1`. That is nonsense.

Comment: sorry i am new to php and very new to pdo. I all ready done this using mysql its working. $sql= "INSERT INTO `authentication`.`orders` (`customer_id`, `date`) VALUES ('$customer_id', '$d');";
 
$result=mysql_query($sql);
$lastid = mysql_insert_id();

if($result==1)
{

Comment: Well, what is `if($result==1)` supposed to test?

Comment: is value inserted or not

Comment: Consider this [special note to JSON API writers](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes#json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$conn->query($sql)` returns either a `PDOStatement` object upon success, or `false` on failure. Comparing either to `== 1` is nonsense. It was nonsense in the times of `mysql_query`, and is still nonsense in the times of PDO. You want to test the result for *truthiness*, not against a numeral.

It's as simple as:

```
if ($result)
```

Comment: if ($result) is superfluous too :) there should be an exception that will just prevent all the following code from running

Comment: Arguably so, if PDO was set up appropriately. I don't feel like discussing the nuances of error handling strategies though at the moment... ;)

Comment: :) thank u sir for your help and for your valuable time